# Issues with variables in bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have `error_reporting` all the way on and I've looked over it many times, so I think I might be calling a value wrong or didn't declare something correct.  Anyone who can jump in and tell me whats up with the code and why still the error " Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" because I'm stumped:

```
$db=new mySQLi($host,$dbhuser,$dbhpwd,$dbh); 
$insert_stmt = $db->stmt_init();    
$insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO food (id,timestamp,userid,tagline,group,location,event_date,event_time,image,type) VALUES(NULL,NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $insert_stmt->bind_param("issssssi",$_SESSION['id'],$tagline,$organizer,$location,$event_date,$event_time,$image_name,$food_id);
        $insert_stmt->execute();
```

userid is an integer that I pull from a stored cookie.

$tagline, $organizer, $location, are text with max at 140 chars.

$event_date = $event_date= substr(date('Y'),0,2).$year."-".$month."-".$day;
$event_time= date("H:i:s", strtotime($hour.":".$minute.$period));
- all these variable were users input as two digit numbers as text

$image_name is text, a file path

and type is an integer from 1-29.

Here is an example result of the ? values for the database: 38, test, test, test, 2013-2-20, 14:15:00, Halloween_Beer_2.jpg, 7

Here is a screen shot of the setup in mysql for the table called food:
[image]

Comment: yeah, I'm using mySQLi.  I call the $db a couple of lines earlier with $db=new mySQLi($host,$dbhuser,$dbhpwd,$dbh);

Comment: the error message includes the line number. They do that, to help you fix your error.

Comment: yep, the line number is 177 and the line is the bind-param on the code above.  I know I either didn't prepare something correct or I'm calling the bind_param incorrect, but at I'm at a loss as to where...

Comment: same error with the issue with bind_param from the prepared stated beforehand.

Comment: that was more helpful: Notice: Array to string conversion

Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$Array  Nice :)

Comment: `$db-> error` produces a notice of array to string conversion and the undefined property.  None of my variable though are arrays...hmm.

Comment: Honestly speaking, it just doesn't make any sense. Can you show some more code of yours WITH those debugging statements?

Answer (score -2):

```
$insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO food (id,timestamp,userid,tagline,group,location,event_date,event_time,image,type) VALUES(NULL,NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $insert_stmt->bind_param("issssssi",$_SESSION['id'],$tagline,$organizer,$location,$event_date,$event_time,$image_name,$food_id);
        $insert_stmt->execute();
```

you are doing wrong.`BindParam` accepts only a single value

```
$query->bindParam("value",":value",PDO::PARAM_INT);// type
```

you can do something like this

```
   $insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO food (id,timestamp,userid,tagline,group,location,event_date,event_time,image,type) VALUES(NULL,NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$insert_stmt->execute(array("issssssi",$_SESSION['id'],$tagline,$organizer,$location,$event_date,$event_time,$image_name,$food_id))
```

Or you can see this
       [PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: It's PDO answer in MySQLi question.

Comment: @raina77ow OP didn't mention that he is using mysqli.Even there is no `mysqli` tag

Comment: Of course, he should have done it. Yet he mentioned `stmt_init` and `bind_param` methods.

Comment: @raina77ow i am using PDO and i don't know `mysqli` functions...`bind_param` is also used in pdo..So i just answered

Comment: Ahem. Your answer is like "you're doing it wrong, there's no `ls` command in Windows, use `dir` instead" - even though the OP doesn't mention using Windows (or Linux, for that matter).

Comment: @raina77ow don't be over-smart...How could i know Op is using mysqli even if he is not mentioning it anywhere?He has problem with `bindParam` and i just solved that..So is there any problem with you?